# content moving below the cube

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can you tell how to make the content fixed.
i mean the content should not go below the cube image when the user resizes the window 
when i see it in big screen its not problem
when i see it in the small screens laptop like 13 inch its problem
providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/AJ5JW/

```
<section id="main" style="padding: 0px;">
            <div class="inner clearfix defieContainer" style="">
              <img alt="cube" class="cubeImage" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/cube.png">
                  <div class="defieHomepageContent">
                    <span style="color: #06546a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;  ">Defie Cloud Buisness Solutions</span> helps companies of all sizes to enhance business operation, to refine the process and optimize technology, to reduce company 
                    expenses on IT maintenance, Hardware upgrade. And more importantly, to change 
                    the way businesses operate.
                    <div id="primary">
                      <section class="primary">
                        We Offer:
                        <ul class="homePageLists" style="">
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; ">
                              <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                                 All-in-One Business Management Solutions
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; ">
                              <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                              Cloud-based File Management
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; ">
                              <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                              Real-Time Access from any where, any time and on any devices
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </section>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: You have small box for content there, just `65.8% - 250px`. Try to make it bigger or fixed size.

Comment: @antejan: thanks for your reply. can you update the code in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AJ5JW/

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your code in a browser, no where does the content move above the box, i am viewing from a 23 inch monitor and even when i resize it, it does not show up below the box.

Comment: it should not move below the box how to fix it